# Fable D3 map sample

Tags: d3.js, f#, fable-f#

I'm trying to run a Fable [D3 map sample](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/blob/master/samples/browser/d3map/d3map.fsx) and I see it requires a browser [server module](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/tree/master/samples/browser/server).
When I try to

```
npm run build
```

under the d3 folder it compiles

```
npm run build

> @ build C:\...\d3
> node ../node_modules/fable-compiler

fable-compiler 0.7.50: Start compilation...
Compiled fable-import-d3\Fable.Import.D3.js at 03:00:47
Compiled d3\d3map.js at 03:00:48
Bundling...
Bundled out\bundle.js at 03:00:48
```

but then after

```
npm start
```

the browser at `http://localhost:8080/` gets an Uncaught Error, `SCRIPT5009` `'Symbol' not defined`:

```
   if (typeof globalObj.__FABLE_CORE__ === "undefined") {
    globalObj.__FABLE_CORE__ = {
        types: new Map(),
        symbols: {
            reflection: Symbol("reflection"),
        }
    };
```

**Edit**

above problem was only related to IE11 (not to Chrome) and it's solved by adding

```
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/core.js"></script>
```

in `index.html`

Now both IE11 and latest Chrome version raise

```
queue.v1.js:14 Uncaught Error
    at newQueue (queue.v1.js:14)
    at queue (queue.v1.js:109)
    at d3.d_map (d3map.fsx:201)
    at d3map.fsx:201
```

where `queue.v1.js:14` is

```
function newQueue(concurrency) {
  if (!(concurrency >= 1)) throw new Error;
```

because `concurrency` is zero... (all this refers to `fable-compiler 0.7.50`).

Comment: I think `Symbol` is not defined error basically means you need to add a reference to polyfill like core.js: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js Best way of handling this changes daily (this is the JS world), but adding reference to corejs worked for me :)

Comment: @TomasPetricek does it mean also that - alternatively - there could be a browser version to be updated on the client or something else on the npm server side? Or the way to go is just to add a reference that I missed? The original [D3 demo](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4183330) in pure JS was working fine: isn't the Fable port handling which would require such frequent updates?

Comment: The Fable version (http://fable.io/samples/d3map/index.html) references `core.js`. I believe it is also possible to inline this during the Fable compilation, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I'd be happy to accept an answer that tells me to do like the Fable version, referencing `core.js`, but actually I've copied this [d3map.fsx](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/blob/master/samples/browser/d3map/d3map.fsx), so it already contains `open Fable.Core.JsInterop`. Not sure where I went wrong though.

Comment: BTW Now I'm noticing that [latest commit for `samples/browser/d3map/package.json`](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/commit/edc98c028fc4f7d5bebdf047dca13dd912e721c4#diff-d57fae326ccb8260f603a9f3cc1e086d) removed `-  "dependencies": {
 -    "core-js": "^2.4.0",` etc... (I wonder whether it has to do with the issue somehow?)

Comment: In case you do not get a reply here, try asking in the Fable gitter room: https://gitter.im/fable-compiler/Fable

Comment: @TomasPetricek Thank you! I've posted [there](https://gitter.im/fable-compiler/Fable?at=5900e0a908c00c092abb0509) the details of the log from the debugger with latest version of Chrome browser...

Comment: Sorry, I haven't update repo samples to Fable 1.0 beta. I just did it for the d3map sample in the [update-samples](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/tree/update-samples/samples/browser/d3map) branch. Can you give it a try? There're instructions in the README file.

Comment: @AlfonsoGarcia-Caro Thank you! will do for sure later tonight. I was writing an answer myself to recap the replies from gitter, but I'd be happier to accept an answer from one of you :-) thank you so much again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server module is just a custom local server to host the sample. [Fable 1.0 beta](http://fable.io/blog/Introducing-1-0-beta.html) integrates with Webpack and Webpack Dev Server so that's not necessary. I've updated the d3 sample [here](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/tree/update-samples/samples/browser/d3map), can you please give it a try? The new sample also includes the [transform-runtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-runtime) Babel plugin which automatically inserts the necessary polyfills (like Symbol) in your bundle so you don't have to worry about the core.js dependency :)

Comment: Awesome! Out of my curiosity, 1) would it make sense and would it *still* be possible to run the version 0.7 fixing the above errors *without* upgrading *yet* to the new beta version 1.0? 2) even though this is ported to .fsx, it is heavily dependent on JavaScript and D3 libraries:  where is the possibility to leverage more the F#? 2 bis) is it normal that Visual Studio Code doesn't understand the syntax of some D3 lines? Which is the appropriate editor/IDE?

Comment: 1) I guess so, in that case I'd just core-js in a script tag in you web page before loading the fable code, as Tomas commented above. 2) For other libraries like React an intermediate layer has been created to be able to make the interaction more idiomatic in F#, but of course this requires a maintenance effort. There are many libs that "simplify" D3, I'd pick one and if necessary create the intermediate layer for it. 3) I think VS Code/Ionide sometimes doesn't do autocompletion after using the dot 3 times to access members. Any IDE will do, but atm not all IDEs support the new project format.

Comment: "*I'd just core-js in a script tag in you web page before loading the fable code, as Tomas commented above.*" **Sorry** for making a lot of confusion! Ok Tomas was right and `Symbol undefined` is solved, in fact my problem is different, I've posted it in [gitter](https://gitter.im/fable-compiler/Fable?at=5900e0a908c00c092abb0509). `Uncaught Error at newQueue (queue.v1.js:14)` i.e `if (!(concurrency >= 1)) throw new Error;` and concurrency is 0... I know your solution is perfect, but I'm asking just for the sake of understanding and fixing this error with the old version...

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the error (`queue.v1.js:14 Uncaught Error`) in my edit (for `fable-compiler 0.7.50`) by defining ([line 33](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/blob/master/samples/browser/d3map/d3map.fsx#L33))

```
let queue = importDefault<int->obj> "queue"
```

with `int` instead of `unit` and then calling

```
queue(2)
```

at [line 201](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/blob/master/samples/browser/d3map/d3map.fsx#L201) instead of the empty c.tor `queue()`

### Alternative, more elegant solution

As per [line 33](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/blob/update-samples/samples/browser/d3map/d3map.fs#L33) of the new d3 sample linked to Alfonso Garcia-Caro's answer, we can just replace the queue definition with

```
let queue() = importDefault "queue"
```

and then use the simple `queue()` c.tor *without* arg

**minor note**

Notice that restoring the old line with

```
let queue = importDefault<unit->obj> "queue"
```

into the new sample with Fable 1.0 (integrated with Webpack Dev Server) doesn't cause any error. Oddly enough, IMHO it's only a strange behavior of the `importDefault` in `fable-compiler 0.7.50`